# Google App Script Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I have this code to export my Google sheets to a 'CSV' delimited tab "|" thanks to the help @iansedano.

So this is the script:

```
function createCsvContent(values, delimiter) {

  // This converts the values 2D array into a simple array of strings delimited by the delimiter
  const stringArray = values.map(row => row.join(delimiter))
  // Then it joins all the strings with newlines
  const output = stringArray.join("\n")

  return output
}


function createCsv() {
  // Get all the values from the sheet as a 2D array
  const file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = file.getSheetByName("LIST");
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const values = range.getValues();

  // call the function to create the csv-like content
  const csvContent = createCsvContent(values, "|")

  // create the file in drive
  //DriveApp.createFile('csvFile', csvContent, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
  DriveApp.getFileById("[10eI7WAO688nQHRqj7ymscN5I5fJpP4fVTUn_qZMuq3Y]").setContent(csvContent)
}
```

So each time I run the script, I want to overwrite this file https://docs.google.com/document/d/10eI7WAO688nQHRqj7ymscN5I5fJpP4fVTUn_qZMuq3Y/edit.

I cant file the proper File ID of this. If i am not wrong, this is not the file ID '10eI7WAO688nQHRqj7ymscN5I5fJpP4fVTUn_qZMuq3Y'.

Where i can get the real ID of the Google Doc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the value of `[10eI7WAO688nQHRqj7ymscN5I5fJpP4fVTUn_qZMuq3Y]` as the file ID, please modify it to `10eI7WAO688nQHRqj7ymscN5I5fJpP4fVTUn_qZMuq3Y`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/overview#document_id) So, when your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
DriveApp.getFileById("[10eI7WAO688nQHRqj7ymscN5I5fJpP4fVTUn_qZMuq3Y]").setContent(csvContent)
```

#### To:

```
DriveApp.getFileById("10eI7WAO688nQHRqj7ymscN5I5fJpP4fVTUn_qZMuq3Y").setContent(csvContent);
```

#### Note:

- If you want to directly use the URL of `https://docs.google.com/document/d/###/edit`, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/###/edit").getBody().setText(csvContent);
  ```

#### Reference:

- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)

Comment: @Simon GIS Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.